# How to Prevent Browser Control from URLDecoding an Embedded URL Link

Tags: html, url, href, url-encoding

Please forgive my lack of knowledge surrounding HTML

I am trying to generate a static HTML page which is rendered in an embedded HTML Browser component in a 3rd party application.

In the HTML Body I have a URL Link embedded within the page.

```
<a href="https://mydomain.com.au/Web/Default.ashx?encrypt=x%2BNWTAVMqprD%2BZyFtf1tfBVfIfhqKJ3JCjMmiXiSJSUl6n4FzCuW8mwQfpNskdQEvqU7QiWMdR%2Bbu9y6%2BiO8eh41XwGJX9l5iCYZunTamhGdkkiR9CqVCrkStu%2BzAlhqcJYG6M0zztcActpm6iSn99gXDlw8z%2BHs8Q88N9fZyXdYpxspgl%2BAoGZe7hR3zOulJb1YhabyBbf%2BkfI0dq1YQpHn3SWig8HuWvBANXPrPHDqAOsnT1DtJQ%3D%3D" class="Action">Access Application</a>
```

Note that the above URL is "URLEncoded". Specifically, the query string after "encrypt=" is encrypted, and then URLEncoded.

**Problem**

The HTML browser component embedded in the 3rd party application renders the HTML and all appears fine, EXCEPT that it Decodes the URL String.

This results in a hyperlink with the following URI;

```
https://mydomain.com.au/Web/Default.ashx?encrypt=x+NWTAVMqprD+ZyFtf1tfBVfIfhqKJ3JCjMmiXiSJSUl6n4FzCuW8mwQfpNskdQEvqU7QiWMdR+bu9y6+iO8eh41XwGJX9l5iCYZunTamhGdkkiR9CqVCrkStu+zAlhqcJYG6M0zztcActpm6iSn99gXDlw8z+Hs8Q88N9fZyXdYpxspgl+AoGZe7hR3zOulJb1YhabyBbf+kfI0dq1YQpHn3SWig8HuWvBANXPrPHDqAOsnT1DtJQ==
```

Note the now existance of characters such as "+" and "=" which causes the failure to load the application which is the target of the URL.

Is there any way to prevent a browser (browser control?) from decoding this URL string and maintaining its integrity?

I am thinking off the top of my head, and I don't really understand the purpose of this suggestion but will defining a "type" attribute on the Link  such as

```
<a type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" href="xxx.com/ddddd" class="Action">Access Application</a>
```

have any effect?

How else can I prevent the browser control from decoding this URL?

Meta Tags in the  < head > ???

Thanks in Advance!

Kind Regards

Aaron

Comment: Are you tryed `encodeURIComponent(myUrl);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to escape the % symbol.

For example: changing %2B in the link to %252B (%25 being the escape code for a % symbol). Likewise changing %3D to %253D had the same effect and prevent the client application rendering %3D to a = sign.

We couldn't stop the client application from 'decoding' the URL entirely but at least now it decoded to the correct URL value